What is the mistake in my queue_poll function in C?
Im currently trying to implement a queue poll function, which polls the last element from the queue. I really don't understand why this function does not work. The logic behind the function should be pretty simple but it seems like it isn't. I would be interested to know why I can't use pointers like that.
void *queue_poll(queue_object *queue) {
    if (queue == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    queue_object *prev = queue;
    while (prev->next != NULL) {
        queue_object *tmp = prev->next;
        prev = tmp;
    }
    void *object = prev->object;
    free(prev);
    return object;
}

I've tried to print the values to debug the issue but nothing happens. Im really stuck here. I would appreciate any help.
int main(void) {

    char *A = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *B = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *C = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *D = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *E = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *F = malloc(sizeof(char));

    *A = 'A';
    *B = 'B';
    *C = 'C';
    *D = 'D';
    *E = 'E';
    *F = 'F';

    FCFS_startup();

    queue_add(A, FCFS_queue);
    queue_add(B, FCFS_queue);
    queue_add(C, FCFS_queue);
    queue_add(D, FCFS_queue);
    queue_add(E, FCFS_queue);
    queue_add(F, FCFS_queue);

    void *value = queue_poll(FCFS_queue);

    printf("%c\n", *(char*)value);
}

Thank you in advance.
Kind regards.
I've tried to use prev != NULL instead of prev->next != NULL but still nothing gets printed.
queue_add:
int queue_add(void *new_object, queue_object *queue) {
    if (queue == NULL || new_object == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    queue_object *object = new_queue();
    if (object == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    void *tmp = queue->object;
    object->object = tmp;
    object->next = queue->next;
    queue->next = object;
    queue->object = new_object;
    return 0;
}

FCFS_startup:
int FCFS_startup()
{
    FCFS_queue = new_queue();
    if (FCFS_queue == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

new_queue:
queue_object *new_queue() {
    queue_object *new_object = (queue_object*)malloc(sizeof(queue_object));
    if (new_object == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    new_object->next = NULL;
    new_object->object = NULL;
    return new_object;
}

queue_object:
typedef struct _queue_object {
    void *object;
    struct _queue_object *next;
} queue_object;


We don't know what queue_add does, or how queue_object looks like. Please post a [mre].

@checkchecker In any case the function queue_poll is wrong because the data member next of the node that precedes the node that is deleted is not correctly updated. Consider for example a queue that contains only one node.

Unrelated: If you change void main(void) into int main(void) a lot more people can compile your program - or, they would be able to if you'd made a [mre].

You may want to run this in a debugger or add fprintf(stderr, "value = %p\n", value); after queue_poll in main. Hint: value == NULL.

what is a minimal reproducible example?

Did you follow the link? It describes it. A minimal reproducible example could look like this although it could be shortened down a bit.

@checkchecker  The minimal reproducible example is a complete minimal program that demonstrates the problem. Till now you have not provided such a program.

@checkchecker The function FCFS_startup does not make sense becuase it creates a node of the queue without storing an actual data.

@checkchecker The function queue_poll is wrong becuase it does not update the queue.

@checkchecker Using the same identifier for two different entities like  in this statement object->object = tmp; makes your code unreadable.

Reduce the number of calls to queue_add down to one. Draw the state of the queue after that call on the piece of paper (objects are rectangles and pointers are arrows). See something suspicious? If not, make a snapshot and post it in the question.

Your use of terminology is confusing.  "Queue" conventionally names a data structure providing multiple-item storage with first-in / first-out semantics. To "poll" a queue conventionally means to retrieve the next available item from it, if any.  And that item is best described as the first element, not the last, notwithstanding the internal implementation of the queue.

@checkchecker By reducing and simplifying the code, the error disappeared. Demo. I didn't pay attention to when it disappeared but perhaps you find something useful in my version.

You are using a linked list node with null next and null object to represent an empty list.  You are also performing your insertions at the head of the list, so that performing a series of adds on an initially-empty list will leave the last node being one representing an empty (tail) list.  This is workable, but awkward.
There are then multiple problems with your queue_poll(), most notably:

When applied to a linked list (queue) prepared via a series of such adds, this ...

queue_object *prev = queue;
while (prev->next != NULL) {
    queue_object *tmp = prev->next;
    prev = tmp;
}


... leaves prev pointing to the node whose next is null, which is that initial node representing an empty list, not one containing real data.

Furthermore, this ...

void *object = prev->object;
free(prev);


... frees the node to which prev points without first removing it from the list, thus corrupting it the list.


Suggestions:

Having a dummy node to represent an empty list can be very useful, but when you do that with a singly-linked list, it works a lot better to maintain the dummy node as the head node instead of the tail node.

Especially if you are going to do this with a singly-linked list, consider (additionally) having a separate structure representing the overall list / queue, in which you store both a head node [not necessarily a pointer] and a tail pointer.  This way, you will not have to iterate through all the entries to find the end.

Run your queue in the opposite direction, with the first-added element at the head and the last-added one at the tail.  With a singly-linked list, removals benefit from being performed at the head more than additions do.

Make sure to update the list structure when you remove an element.  This will, again, be easier if you're removing from the head instead of from the tail.


